# Python time.sleep() does not work in linux and multi thread

Tags: python, python-3.4

I write a simple multiprocess and multi-thread code in python which works in windows but doesn't work in linux (i tested it on freebsd and ubuntu)

```
import threading
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

class Test(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        print('before sleep')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('after sleep')

def run_test():
    Test().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Process(target=run_test, args=()).start()
```

this program only print "before sleep" and then exit.

why sleep doesn't work here? (it works on windows)

UPDATE:

I used join() in my process like this, but still not work.

```
...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pr = Process(target=run_test, args=())
    pr.start()
    pr.join()
```

Comment: the `main` process and the process spawned both terminate before the thread has the chance to print the rest. You should make them wait/join (hint)

Comment: @Pynchia, I test .join() and sleep in main process, but it doesn't work.

Comment: BTW, if `Test` inherits from `Thread`, why override `__init__` if it does nothing else?

Comment: alright, then post some more code, please. I have replied based on what you have shown.

Comment: @Pynchia, That's right, it's my mistake about `__init__` I corrected it.

Comment: @Pynchia, this is all of the code, `sleep` in main process works, but in thread with multiprocessing doesn't work!

Comment: You still do not join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The join() should be used in the calling thread to wait for another thread:

```
def run_test():
    t = Test()
    t.start()
    t.join()
```